# Loop on a data frame to create multiple excels/csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python programming, and I am trying to think how to create multiple excels from a data frame.  I have a Pandas data frame as shown below,

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID |
| --- | --- |
| MHI000000038710 | 100039 |
| MHI000000038711 | 100043 |
| MHI000000038712 | 100043 |

I am trying to create excels for every Invoice No. from data frame. For the above example, the output would be 3 excels named after each Invoice No. (i.e., MHI000000038710, MHI000000038711, MHI000000038712).

And each excel should contains rows grouped by Voucher ID

Excel 1(MHI000000038710.xlsx): -

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID |
| --- | --- |
| MHI000000038710 | 100039 |

Excel 2(MHI000000038711.xlsx): -

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID |
| --- | --- |
| MHI000000038711 | 100043 |
| MHI000000038712 | 100043 |

Excel 3(MHI000000038712.xlsx): -

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID |
| --- | --- |
| MHI000000038711 | 100043 |
| MHI000000038712 | 100043 |

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with specific problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried to solve this. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

1. First iterate over a list of unique voucher IDs and select only rows matching this ID.
2. For each temporary dataframe (`df_singleID`) created this way, iterate over the unique Invoice No. and use this name to create your output file name:

Assuming that your pandas dataframe is named `df`, this can be done as shown below:

```
for myid in df['VoucherID'].unique()
    df_singleID = df[df['VoucherID']==myid]
    for myinvoice in df_singleID['Invoice No.'].unique():
        df_singleID.to_excel('./'+str(myinvoice)+'.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe this should work:

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[df["Voucher ID"] == row["Voucher ID"]].to_excel(f'{row["Invoice No."]}.xlsx')
```